# If the hadoop cluster is configured to utilise kerberos authentication, then should MapReduce job need to be configured to handle it?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

If the hadoop cluster is configured to utilise kerberos authentication, then should the MapReduce job need to be configured to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires something like this:

```
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
```